# Finding address of local variable defined inside shared library function

Tags: c, linux, gcc, assembly

I have created a shared library which contain 3 different functions.
Inside funcA function, there is one local variable, an array of size 10.
funcA calls funcB and pass base address of arr1 and no of element.

funcB calls funcC and pass base address of arr2 (indirectly base address of arr1) and no of element.

Inside funcC I am accessing all elements of array . **As I am passing
argument as reference,so whenever I will access array elements inside
funcC , it will indirectly access Memory Address of ORIGINAL array, arr1.**

How I can find memory address of arr1 , outside of funcA ( may be in other thread or program2). I know that 
once I will be out of funcA, address assigned to arr1 is invalid .

I want to check whether memory address of arr1 is accessed or not while 
executing funcC , how can I do that ?

**I can't define arr1 as extern or static.**

**Here is my program**

```
#include<stdio.h>

funcA()
{
int *arr1=malloc(10*sizeof(int));
int n;
for(n=0;n<10;n++)
arr1[n]=n+1;
for(n=0;n<15;n++)
  {
   funcB(arr1,10);
  }
}

funcB(int *arr2,int n)
{   
funcC(arr2,n);
}

funcC(int *arr3,int n)
{
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    *(arr3+i)*=2; // Accessing local array element of funcA
}


main()
{
funcA();
}
```

First, I tried with generating assembly from C. There I got the relationship that array stored in stack and can be accessed with respect to ebp ( don't understand how to access particular address like [ebp-40] from c program ?).

Then I used gdb to find the address of funcA and arr1 , but not able to understand how to confirm I am getting correct address of arr1 ?

I am using gcc under ubuntu12.04. Any help to understand or any link will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Problem #1: `arr1` doesn't exist outside of `funcA`. It exists on the call stack, only as long as `funcA` does.

Comment: I think that if arr1 is not dynamically allocated the memory address of it will change every time you call the function...

Comment: Note that there is not a single "variable" `arr1`. For each invocation of `funcA` there is a corresponding `arr1`. There could be none at all (when `funcA` is not running) or more than one (if `funcA` is called recursively, including from a signal handler, or from multiple threads).

Comment: Why exactly do you ask?

Comment: @DGomez , arr1 is dynamically allocated the memory address. I have corrected my program.

Answer (score 1):

A local variable exists only when the function in which it is declared has an active frame on the [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) (and technically, when the block declaring that local is active).

Notice that for a recursive function, you'll got several local variables (one per call frame). Also, if several threads have active frames for that same function declaring that variable, each active call frame has such an address for the local variable. At last, the compiler would optimize some variables and might not use any stack slot for some of them (e.g. by putting that variable in a register; read about [register allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_allocation#Spilling)).

So you cannot find the address of a local variable, because that local variable might not exist -no active call frames for its function- or exists multiply -several active call frames for a [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29)-.

<sup>So your question has no sense!</sup>

Of course, you could store -with some code in the function declaring that local- the address of a local variable somewhere (e.g. in a global, in a field of some record in the heap, etc...). That address would become invalid when you have exited (or returned) from the block declaring it. Using or dereferencing such an invalid address is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: I have updated my program to make it sensible. Local variable of funcA is active in stack while funcB/funcC are recursively called. Another point, I am actually using another data type, BIGNUM which will not fit in register, so it will definitely store in stack.

Answer (score -1):

Print the address of the pointer it will be the same which means all your pointers are pointing to the same memory location.

```
funcA()
    {
       int arr1[10];
       int n;
       for(n=0;n<10;n++)
          arr1[n]=n+1;
       printf("%p\n",arr1);
       funcB(arr1,10);
    }

    funcB(int *arr2,int n)
    {
       printf("%p\n",arr2);

       funcC(arr2,n);
    }

    funcC(int *arr3,int n)
    {
       int i=0;
       printf("%p\n",arr3);
       for(i=0;i<n;i++)
          printf("%d \n",*(arr3+i));
    }
```